# PostgreSQL Serialized Inserts Interleaving Sequence Numbers

Tags: postgresql

I have multiple processes inserting into a Postgres (10.3) table using the SERIALIZED isolation level.

Another part of our system needs to read these records and be guaranteed that it receives all of them in sequence. For example, in the picture below, the consumer would need to

```
select * from table where sequanceNum > 2309 limit 5
```

and then receive sequence numbers 2310, 2311, 2312, 2313 and 2314.

The reading query is using READCOMMITTED isolation level.

What I'm seeing though is that the reading query is only receiving the rows I've highlighted in yellow. Looking at the xmin, I'm guessing that transaction 334250 had begun but not finished, then transactions 334251, 334252 et al started and finished prior to my reading query starting.

My question is, how did they get sequence numbers interleaved in those of 334250? Why weren't those transactions blocked by merrit of all of the writing transactions being serialized?

Any suggestions on how to achieve what I'm after? Which is, a guarantee that different transactions don't generate interleaving sequence numbers? (It's ok if there are gaps.... but they can't interleave).

Thanks very much for your help. I'm losing hair over this one!

PS - I just noticed that 334250 has a non zero xmax. Is that a clue that I'm missing perhaps?

[image]

Comment: Duplicate of question posted here. Sorry if this is breaking some Stack Exchange law I'm unaware of! https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/218107/postgresql-serialized-inserts-interleaving-sequence-numbers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SQL standard in its usual brevity defines `SERIALIZABLE` as:

> The execution of concurrent SQL-transactions at isolation level `SERIALIZABLE` is guaranteed to be serializable.
>   A serializable execution is defined to be an execution of the operations of concurrently executing SQL-transactions
>   that produces the same effect as some serial execution of those same SQL-transactions. A serial execution
>   is one in which each SQL-transaction executes to completion before the next SQL-transaction begins.

In the light of this definition, I understand that your wish is that the sequence numbers be in the same order as the “serial execution” that “produces the same effect”.

Unfortunately the equivalent serial ordering is not clear at the time the transactions begin, because statements later in the transaction can determine the “logical” order of the transactions.

Sequence numbers on the other hand are ordered according to the wall time when the number was requested.

In a way, you would need sequence numbers that are determined by something that is not certain until the transactions commit, and that is a contradiction in terms.

So I think that it is not possible to get what you want, unless you actually serialize the execution, e.g. by locking the table in `SHARE ROW EXCLUSIVE` mode before you insert the data.

My question is **why** you have that unusual demand. I cannot think of a good reason.

Comment: Thanks for that. The data is an event store. There's a strict requirement that readers process it in sequence, hence the unusual demand. The SHARE ROW EXCLUSIVE suggestion was a good one and sent me down the rabbit hole of reading - however it didn't scale due to locking the whole table. I've now put a SELECT into each transaction which gets the current max value, then increment it in my code before writing it back - taking the task away from PG. It seems to be working and scaling acceptably. Thank you! All the real learning happens when stuff breaks :-)

Comment: As a follow up with this, I ended up switching to using Postgres Advisory Locks which seem to work well. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/explicit-locking.html